# gvNIX: Error installing datatables

Tags: gvnix, gvnix-es

I was working with gvNIX after installing jQuery and everything worked fine. But, when I installed the datatables `web mvc datatables setup` and the app was compiled, the web crashed and the server shown this error:

```
2015-05-25 12:47:34,583 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/home/vicente/Documentos/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/FitTrainning_WebService/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you deploying on a JBoss? There is a problem due JPA API version (JBoss includes 2.0 but gvNIX requires 2.1).

Take a look [this issue on JBoss Jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209) for a workaround.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't install JBoss. Should I install it?

Comment: No. I just supposed it. So, I think some dependency is missing in your war or there is a library version conflict. Review JPA API version in your pom.xml (`mvn dependecy:tree` can help you on it). Also, Check if this library is included into the generated war. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe there is a dependency missed, because the JPA API version is 2.1. Is there any way to know which dependency is missing?